# javascript form validation won't return true

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, return, onsubmit

Trying to learn JS and seem to be coming along okay, but getting stuck on this form validation... It should validate that text boxes are not left empty or with the default value. Can get alert to pop up when validation returns false, but after entering info into the fields, the form does not return true to submit..

Any help is appreciated. See code below:

```js
function validateFunc() {
  var nameField = document.forms[0].visitor_name.value
  var emailField = document.forms[0].email.value
  var phoneField = document.forms[0].phone.value
  var areaField = document.forms[0].area.value
  if (nameField || emailField || phoneField || areaField === "") { 
    window.alert("Please fill out all fields!");
    return false;
  }
  else {
    return true        
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="FormProcessor.html" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit= "return validateFunc()">
  <p>Name<br />
    <input type="text" name="visitor_name" size="50"/ value="Enter your name" onclick="if (this.value == 'Enter your name') this.value='';">    
  </p>
  <p>E-mail Address<br />
    <input type="text" name="email" size="50" value="Enter your email address" onclick="if (this.value == 'Enter your email address') this.value='';"/>    
  </p>
  <p>Phone<br />
    <input type="text" name="phone" size="50" value="Enter your phone number" onclick="if (this.value == 'Enter your phone number') this.value='';"/>    
  </p>
  <p>Area of town<br />
    <input type="text" name="area" size="50" value="What area of town are you interested in?" onchange="noEmptyBoxes()" onclick="if (this.value == 'What area of town are you interested in?') this.value='';"/>    
  </p>
  <p>Property
    <select name="property_type">
      <option value="unselected">Select a property type</option> 
      <option value="condo">Condos</option> 
      <option value="single">Single Family Homes</option> 
      <option value="multi">Multifamily Homes</option> 
      <option value="mobile">Mobile Homes</option> 
      <option value="land">Land</option> 
    </select>
    Sq. feet <input type="text" name="feet" size="5" value="???" onclick="if (this.value == '???') this.value='';"/>    
  </p>
  <p>Bedrooms <input type="text" name="bedrooms" size="5" value="???" onclick="if (this.value == '???') this.value='';"/>
    Maximum Price <input type="text" name="price" size="12" value="$$$" onclick="if (this.value == '$$$') this.value='';"/>     
  </p>
  <p>How should we contact you?
    <input type="radio" name="contactHow" value="call_me"/>Call me
    <input type="radio" name="contactHow" value="e-mail_me"/>Email me    
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit"/>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: `if (nameField || emailField || phoneField || areaField === "")`. What do you think this code does?

Comment: Learning [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) might be useful?

Comment: @Teemu definitely useful for a noob to js like me. thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a variable is a blank string, then the statement `if (nameField)` will return false.

Your statement is equivalent to:

```
if ( (nameField is NOT blank) OR 
     (emailField is NOT blank) OR
     (phoneField is NOT blank) OR
     (areaField IS blank) )
```

To check whether any of the variables is blank, include the comparison for each one:

```
if ( nameField=="" || emailField=="" || phoneField=="" || areaField=="" )
```

Find a demonstration, below:

I note that you have not yet coded to check for the default values, so I've removed them for now. I generally use the [`placeholder` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-placeholder) for default values, but [check its compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder) before use.

```js
function validateFunc() {
  var nameField = document.forms[0].visitor_name.value
  var emailField = document.forms[0].email.value
  var phoneField = document.forms[0].phone.value
  var areaField = document.forms[0].area.value
  if (nameField == "" || emailField == "" || phoneField == "" || areaField == "") {
    alert("Please fill out all fields!");
  } else {
    alert("Ready to submit.");
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="FormProcessor.html" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit="return validateFunc()">
  <p>Name <input type="text" name="visitor_name" size="50" value=""></p>
  <p>E-mail Address <input type="text" name="email" size="50" value="" /></p>
  <p>Phone <input type="text" name="phone" size="50" value="" /></p>
  <p>Area of town <input type="text" name="area" size="50" value="" /></p>
  <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Ahhhh... totally makes sense. I assumed the condition would test against  all the variables once it got to the end.. This totally works! Thanks a million!!!